# Joomla 3 permissions setup

Tags: joomla, permissions, joomla3.4

I am using Joomla 3.4.3 and I am trying to give permissions to a specific group. I want this group to `Create/Edit/Delete` articles in a specific category.

I have created a group under `Registered` users. Then in `System -> Global Configuration -> Permissions` I am giving the permission of `Admin Login`, `Access Administration Interface`, etc. 
Take a look at here:
[image: Apply settings]

When I login as a user from this group in the upper menu I can only see the `SP Page Builder` option.
Take a look at here:
[image: User menu panel]

How can I enable the `Content` menu in order to have access (`Create/Edit/Delete`) to the `Categories` and `Articles`? 
I don't want to give `Manager` permissions because I want to give the less the permission I can.

Answer (score 0):

Under `Global Configurations > Permissions` on the left hand side you will see all the components. You have to go to each one and enable or disable them accordingly, this will show the user the relevant menu's on the top.

Comment: When I create a user under "Manager" group and disable "Access Administration Interface" he can only see the "SP Page Builder". But when I enable this option for "Registered" user it seems that it is not working.
Could you be more specific at your response?

Comment: can you add some screenshots, will make figuring the problem out much easier

Comment: I added some PrtScns. I hope this helps!

Comment: can you see where you stated 'it has various options here', you will have to go to each option and configure those permissions as well. Those permissions are for the various menu's on the page and you will have to grant access to the ones that need permission